# select query from remote server in sails js/ waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am using the sails js framework. I have a service in which I am using a query like this:

```
Users.query('select * from remotedb', (err, results) => {
//Do something with results
});
```

I have to use this query from remote database. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to create a connection object. I wrote a snippet which will get this done. Assuming that we use MSSQL server:

```
let sql = require('mssql');
// Make sure that you add 'mssql' node module in your package.json file
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql
// This is Microsoft SQL Server client for Node.js

let sqlConnectionConfig = {
  server: 'Your Database Server URL',
  user: 'Your Username',
  password: 'Your Password',
  database: 'Your Database Name',
};

let connection = new sql.Connection(sqlConnectionConfig);
connection.connect()
  .then(() => {
    new sql.Request(connection)
      .query('SELECT * FROM Role')
      .then(function (recordset) {
        res.send(recordset); // Or do any other fancy stuff
      })
      .catch((sqlServerError) => res.send(sqlServerError));
  })
  .catch((connectionError) => res.send(connectionError));
```

You can change the connection string and driver based on which database you are going to use. Let me know if this worked for you!